# C# RestSharp Cookies

Tags: c#, restsharp

So Im learning RestSharp

But I'm stuck at this problem which is getting specific string for client cookies here is my code:

```
 var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var client = new RestClient("https://server.com")
        {
            UserAgent =
                       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",



        };
        client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("https://server.com"));
        MessageBox.Show(""+cookie);
```

and I always get the cookie empty can anyone helps me?

Comment: What is the `cookie` variable here? You don't set it anywhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("https://server.com"));

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question, don't post it as a comment. And take care of your formatting too.

Comment: Done im sorrryy

Comment: @DavidG so can you help ??

Answer (score 0):

This will set the cookie for your client. After all, you need to do is `client.Execute`. The code is in C# pretty sure you can make it work for anything else.

```cs
string myUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";

client.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("UserAgent", myUserAgent) { Domain = myUri.Host });
```